# Python index of sorted list with consecutive index for runs of ones

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list and I want to find the index of the elements of the sorted list. But I need the index of runs of ones to be consecutive.

I write the following code:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,]
arr = np.array(lst)
print(arr.argsort()[::-1])
```

The output is

```
[ 9  8  5  6 11 10  7  1  2  3  4 19 18 12 13 14 15 16 17  0]
```

But I expect something like:

```
[5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 1 2 3 4 12 13 14 15 16 17]
```

or

```
[11 10 9 8 7 6 5 0 1 2 3 4 12 13 14 15 16 17]
```

The index of runs of ones should be consecutive in the output. What is the pythonic implementation of this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `enumerate` the list, and then sort it based on the value. Since python sort is stable, that will result in the index values remaining sorted as they were originally (i.e. in ascending order) for similar values:

```
lst = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
idxs = [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda v:-v[1])]
print(idxs)
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```